# SAP_HANA ) How to execute a SQL Query with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: odbc, hana

When executing a query that contains Korean(UTF-8), the column name is returned normally, but the data is returned abnormally.

Executed SQL statements and results are as follows:

SQL : SELECT '한글' FROM DUMMY

RESULT :
[image]

The queries you run are encoded in UTF-8. The reason is that the LOCALE executing the query is ko_KR.UTF8, and the Korean alphabet appears normal in the session.

However, SAP HANA DB determines the SQL statement that was created as ASCII.

If the CHAR_AS_UTF8 option is set to true, the above phenomenon appears, and if the CHAR_AS_UTF8 option is set to false, the data appears normally.

Can you explain this phenomenon?

How can I get the result I want?

[image]

The text is broken after SQLPrepare provided by ODBC.

How to change Encoding type of SAP HANA DB Server?
Now, enc          : ASCII

but, we need
enc          : UTF-8